# WPF - Holding modifier keys slows application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

This is a vb.net WPF application.

Holding modifier keys [Shift, Alt, Ctrl] slows this application.

My code rotates a cube when Key.Q is held down.  Pressing Shift+Q, Alt+Q or Ctrl+Q visibly slows down the rotation.

Why is this happening and how to I disable the background key press function that's being called?

Edit - I've tried handling key presses for the modifier keys, i.e. adding variations of "'If e.Key = Key.LeftShift Or e.Key = Key.RightShift Then..." to the key press events but these have not helped.

```
<Viewport3D Name="ViewportMain">

        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="6 5 4" LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <AmbientLight Color="#ffffff" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>

        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="MyModel">
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain" 
                            Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1" 
                            TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate" Axis="0 2 0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>

    </Viewport3D>
```

> 

```
Public WithEvents Timer1 As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
Public ax3d As Media3D.AxisAngleRotation3D
Public myRotateTransform As Media3D.RotateTransform3D
Public isrotating As Boolean = False

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    ax3d = New Media3D.AxisAngleRotation3D(New Media3D.Vector3D(0, 2, 0), 1)
    myRotateTransform = New Media3D.RotateTransform3D(ax3d)
    MyModel.Transform = myRotateTransform

    Timer1.IsEnabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If isrotating Then

        ax3d.Angle += 4

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.IsRepeat Then
        e.Handled = True
        Return
    End If

    If e.Key = Key.Q Then

        isrotating = True

        e.Handled = True

    End If

    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Window_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.Key = Key.Q Then

        isrotating = False

        e.Handled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: They didn't make a difference to speed in my tests, I'm testing under visual studio 2022. When `alt` is pressed the focus goes to the system, that's why your code doesn't work. I don't quite understand why you want to cancel the Q-related key combination.

Comment: If I watch the cube rotating I can see very clearly the animation stutters if I hold any of the modifier keys.  I don't believe it's specific to my computer or due to some other application on my computer.  If pressing alt interrupts my code is there an override for this?  I believe all three modifier keys are causing interruptions and I'd like to find an override for them also.  I don't know what you mean by your last sentence.  I want to be able to hold the key and a modifier and not have the modifier affect my code.  As if I were not holding a modifier key at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the priority for the DispatcherTimer to Render priority fixed the issue.  The default priority is Background.

> "Operations are processed after all other non-idle operations are completed."

Holding the modifier keys Shift, Alt, and Ctrl, as well as CapsLock, would interfere with the DispatcherTimer and cause the timer ticks to be delayed.

Setting the priority to Render allows operations to be processed at the same priority as rendering.  As a result the animation no longer stutters.